AddToCart with variantId from Third Party Script
We're trying to integrate Tolstoy Shoppable Videos onto our Headless Shopify Hydrogen site. I have a component to handle this, however, the add-to-cart is not working so I need to build the custom logic.
From my understanding, and testing, it doesn't look like I can use the standard fetch('/cart/add.js') and would need to utilise the CartProvider and <AddToCartButton> then use state and useEffect to trigger the addToCart once I receive the variantId from Tolstoy.
The variantId is coming back from Tolstoy in the payload just fine, it's passing that to the AddToCart and triggering the event that I think I'm struggling with.
I have tried quite a few variations of this logic but I'm getting nowhere.
import { CartProvider } from '~/provider/cart'
import { AddToCartButton } from '~/components'

import { SectionTolstoyModuleProps } from './TolstoyModule.types'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

interface AddToCartHandlerProps {
  variantId: string
  quantity: number
  onAddToCartSuccess: (payload: any) => void
}

const AddToCartHandler: React.FC<AddToCartHandlerProps> = ({ variantId, quantity, onAddToCartSuccess }) => {
  const [isAdding, setIsAdding] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleTolstoyEvent = (event: MessageEvent) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.eventName === 'tolstoy_add_to_cart') {
        setIsAdding(true)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('message', handleTolstoyEvent)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('message', handleTolstoyEvent)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <CartProvider>
      {isAdding && (
        <AddToCartButton
          lines={[
            {
              quantity: 1,
              merchandiseId: variantId,
            },
          ]}
          variantId={variantId}
          quantity={quantity}
          onSubmit={() => {
            console.log('ON SUBMIT FIRED')
            setIsAdding(false)
            onAddToCartSuccess({ variantId })
          }}
        />
      )}
    </CartProvider>
  )
}

export const TolstoyModule: React.FC<SectionTolstoyModuleProps> = ({
  tags = [],
  publishId,
  productId,
  tolstoyType,
}) => {
  const tagsString = tags?.join(',')

  const handleAddToCartSuccess = (payload: any) => {
    window.tolstoyWidget.postMessage({
      ...payload,
      eventName: 'tolstoy_add_to_cart_success',
    })
  }

  return (
    <div
      data-tags={tagsString}
      className={`tolstoy-${tolstoyType}`}
      data-publish-id={publishId}
      data-product-id={productId}>
      <AddToCartHandler variantId={productId} quantity={1} onAddToCartSuccess={handleAddToCartSuccess} />
    </div>
  )
}


Any help is much appreciated.
